# VBA Runtime Error 438 when using CopyFromRecordset

Tags: excel, vba

When running the below code, I get a 438 runtime error on the CopyFromRecordset line. I figured out my error, but googling this issue was not helpful, so I wanted to post the solution here.

The purpose of the code below is to extract a set of data from a db, paste it into a named range, then resize the named range to fit the new dataset.

```
Sub testCopyRecordset()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.Open connStr
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.Open "Select * from Test;", conn
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

With ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("targetRng")
    .RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(rs.RecordCount)
    .CopyFromRecordset rs
End With  

conn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the reference to the named range. Taking the `CopyFromRecordset` out of the `With` statement, attached to a normally referenced `Range` resolved the error, as per below:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("targetRng")
    .RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(rs.RecordCount)
End With 
Range("targetRng").CopyFromRecordset rs
```